# Why is heap.toArray(new int[0][0]) allowed?

Tags: java, heap

I saw a code like this:

```
public int[][] test() {
       Queue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
       //Do Something 
       return queue.toArray(new int[0][0])
}
```

I'm curious about the last line, why is `int[0][0]` allowed here? Shouldn't the argument to the `queue.toArray` method be the memory that Array restored into?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of `toArray` is here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#toArray(T[])

`toArray`'s signature is `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`.
So the compiler infers `T = int[]`.
Note that the collection's type parameter is `E`, not `T`.

Whatever this code intended to do, most likely it fails, since documentation says:

> Throws: ArrayStoreException - if the runtime type of the specified
>   array is not a supertype of the runtime type of every element in this
>   collection

And `int[]` is not a supertype of `Integer`.

Comment: The implementation of the interface method `toArray` is in `PriorityQueue`, consequently the documentation is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#toArray(T[])

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't the argument to the queue.toArray method be the memory that Array restored into?

Not necessarily.

What happens is that the `toArray` method works out what size array is needed to hold the collection contents.  If the supplied array is large enough, then that is where the contents are written.  Otherwise a new array is allocated and used.  In the latter case, the argument array's actual type determines the type of array that is allocated.

---

As @ReputationFarmer notes, in this case `queue.toArray(new int[0][0])` will probably give a runtime exception (`ArrayStoreException`).  The call *should be* `queue.toArray(new Integer[0])`.

The reason that this doesn't give a compilation error is that the type signature of this `toArray` method is `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)` which allows *any* array type to be passed as an argument.

---

So ... why did they define `toArray` that way?

The answer is in the history of Java:

- The `toArray` methods are specified in the `Collection` API which was added to Java in Java 1.2.
- From Java 1.2 to Java 1.4.2, the signature for this method was:

  ```
  public Object[] toArray(Object[] a)
  ```

  In other words, you could pass an array of any reference type, and the compiler would accept it.
- In Java 5, they introduced generics, and redefined the `toArray` method to have its current signature.

*I suspect* that the reason that they didn't redefine the `toArray` signature to be:

```
    <T extends E> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

is that it would break (give compilation errors) for some Java code that was valid with earlier releases.